# PHP - json_encode show it ascending order by element from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

There are 4 parts of the code:

1. Getting location of a cinema from database
2. Getting distance in KM between user location and cinema
3. Adding distance into array
4. Showing all of it in JSON

So the distance is not something that is in database.

I need to get only 5 results and sort them all in ascending order, so that the closest location will be showing first.

Code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"query to get cinemaname,id,latitude,longitude,cinema logo");

$x = 1; 
while(($rowm = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && ($x <= 5))
{

$lat1 = $_GET['lat'];//users location
$lon1= $_GET['lon'];//users location
$lat2 = $rowm['latitude']; //location of cinema in database
$lon2 = $rowm['longitude']; //location of cinema in database

//calculating the distance by two locations

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = $miles * 1.609344;

$distance = substr($unit,0,4)." km";



$rowm['distance'] = $distance; //adding the distance into the array to show it in json

$asd[]= $rowm;  

$x++; //loop to show it only 5 times
}

$alldata = array('items'=>$asd); //need to show first items to pass it to javascript

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($alldata);
}
?>
```

Result:

```
{"items":[

{"cinemaname":"Cinema name","logo":"upload/logo.png","latitude":"25.2326052","longitude":"55.40300690000004","distance":"29.7 km"},

{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 2","logo":"upload/logo2.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.10300690000004","distance":"19.7 km"},

{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 3","logo":"upload/logo3.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.40200690000004","distance":"6.7 km"},

{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 4","logo":"upload/logo4.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.40200690000004","distance":"4.7 km"},

{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 5","logo":"upload/logo5.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.40200690000004","distance":"5.7 km"}
]}
```

Need to be shown in this way:

```
    {"items":[
      {"cinemaname":"Cinema name 4","logo":"upload/logo4.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.40200690000004","distance":"4.7 km"},

    {"cinemaname":"Cinema name 5","logo":"upload/logo5.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.40200690000004","distance":"5.7 km"},

    {"cinemaname":"Cinema name 3","logo":"upload/logo3.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.40200690000004","distance":"6.7 km"},

 {"cinemaname":"Cinema name 2","logo":"upload/logo2.png","latitude":"25.2226052","longitude":"55.10300690000004","distance":"19.7 km"},


    {"cinemaname":"Cinema name","logo":"upload/logo.png","latitude":"25.2326052","longitude":"55.40300690000004","distance":"29.7 km"}

    ]}
```

So that the smallest distance will be showing first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like this:

```
usort($asd, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['distance'] === $b['distance']) return 0;
    return floatval ($a['distance']) - floatval ($b['distance']) < 0 ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering, almost correct, but still shows the data little bit incorrectly e.g. shows  1,2,4,3,5,6,8,7,9  some of them are showing incorrectly.

Comment: Awesome Ismail, works well, but now there is one another problem if you can help me to solve.. currently it shows randomly 5 locations and distance to them. Now, I need to get only 3 results from all. Is this possible? Thanks a lot to you, you are a nice person.

Comment: You are welcome; You want to get only 3 results from the Database or the Array ?

Comment: From the array, so that on json result will be 3 the most closest,the smallest values of distance.

Comment: Sure! after sorting the array add this `array_splice($asd, 3);`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ismail :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try GLength function in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    *,  GLength(LineString(GeomFromText('POINT(latUser,lngUser)'),GeomFromText('POINT(latCinema,lngCinema)'),))*100 AS DISTANCE
FROM cinema         
ORDER BY DISTANCE LIMIT 5
```